# Erro ao verificar campos na base de dados

Tags: php

```
    //código da classe
    public function ver_utilizadores (){
    $bd = new ligacao_bd();   
    $ver_utilizador = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores";
    $resultado = $bd -> realizarQuery($ver_utilizador);
    return ($resultado);
    }
//codigo do script
if(!$erros){
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        try{
        $verificar = new utilizadores();
        $resultado = $verificar -> ver_utilizadores($username, $email);
        if($resultado -> num_rows >= 1){
        echo "asdasd";
        }else{      
        $insere = new utilizadores();
        $resultado = $insere -> inserir_utilizador($username, $password,$email);
        header('location: login.php');
        }
    }//fim try
        catch (Exception $e){
            echo "Erro de inserção";    
        }
```

Estou a tentar verificar se existem campos iguais ( username e email ) na base de dados, para que se existe não deixe registar.
alguém sabe onde está o erro?
é que ele insere na mesma mesmo que os campo sejam iguais

Comment: Eu acabei entendendo errado, quando vc imprimi(echo) `$resultado->num_rows` aparece o que?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, na terceira linha do seu código na variável  `$ver_utilizador = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores"`, não tem informação do usuário e email logo a chamada do seu método `ver_utilizadores($username, $email)` traz sempre todos os registros da tabela, não fazendo validação alguma se o usuário existe ou não, coloque a cláusula `"WHERE"` no seu SQL utilizando os campos username e email, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE username = ? and email = ?
```